# Class could not be serialized to the desired format

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a class into an XML file that should look like this:

```
<Configuration>
  <LookupTables>
    <Languages>
      <Language>
        <Name>Dutch</Name>
      </Language>
      <Language>
        <Name>French</Name>
      </Language>
    </Languages>
  </LookupTables>
</Configuration>
```

But instead I get this output:

```
<Configuration>
  <LookupTables>
    <Languages>
      <Name>Dutch</Name>
    </Languages>
    <Languages>
      <Name>French</Name>
    </Languages>
  </LookupTables>
</Configuration>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
namespace MyProject
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Configuration", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Configuration_Type
    {
        private LookupTables_Type lookupTablesField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LookupTables")]
        public LookupTables_Type LookupTables
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lookupTablesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lookupTablesField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="LookupTables", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class LookupTables_Type
    {

        private Language_Type[] languagesField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Languages")]
        public Language_Type[] Languages
        {
            get
            {
                return this.languagesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.languagesField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Language", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Language_Type
    {

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute()]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is to declare an Array as `XmlElement`, use the `XmlArray` Attributes instead.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("Languages")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Language")]
public Language_Type[] Languages
{
    get
    {
        return this.languagesField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.languagesField = value;
    }
}
```